# Solving Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

I'm working on a shop program and i'm trying to find the total value of the products in stock. The data related to each item is present in a row of the file named "SHOP.txt", like : "H;L;10;€10,50;83259875;YellowPaint"(that is the first line of the file where all the products are saved in this format, separated by ";" : department,unityOfmeasure,quantity,price,code,name).To calculate the total value, the program read each token from the aforementioned line and calculate the value by multiplying quantity for price.

I already saved in the file about 10 products but when i try to compile my code, I keep getting an error and it calculate the value only of the first product.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            while (running) {
                System.out.println("\nPress 0 to load the inventory. " + "\nPress 1 to save and close"
                        + "\nPress 2 to add products to the inventory" + "\nPress 3 to find products"
                        + "\nPress 4 for the total value of the inventory");
                int answer = in.nextInt();
                switch (answer) {
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("insert the name of the file to load");
                    Loading(in.next());
                    break;
                case 1:
                    saveAndQuit();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    addProduct();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    inputCode();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    inventoryValue();
                    break;

                }
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }

        private static void inventoryValue() throws FileNotFoundException {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("SHOP.txt"));
            scanner.useDelimiter(";|\n");

            Product[] products = new Product[0];
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String department = scanner.next();
                String unityOfMeasure = scanner.next();
                int quantity = scanner.nextInt();
                double price = scanner.nextDouble();
                String code = scanner.next();
                String name = scanner.next();

                Product newProduct = new Product(department, unityOfMeasure, quantity, price, code, name);
                products = newProduct(products, newProduct);

                double totalValue = Arrays.stream(products).mapToDouble(p -> p.quantity * p.price).sum();
                System.out.println("Total Value: " + totalValue + "\n\n");

                for (Product product : products) {
                    System.out.println(product);

                }

            }

        }

        private static Product[] newProduct(Product[] products, Product productToAdd) {
            Product[] newProducts = new Product[products.length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(products, 0, newProducts, 0, products.length);
            newProducts[newProducts.length - 1] = productToAdd;
            return newProduct;
        }
```

This is the complete code as requested.
Product Class:

```
    public class Product implements Serializable {
        protected String department;
        protected String unityOfMeasure;
        protected int quantity;
        protected double price;
        protected String code;
        protected String name;

        private static NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

        public Product(String dep, String uom, int qnt, double prz, String cod, String nm) {

            reparto = dep;
            unitaDiMisura = uom;
            quantità = qnt;
            prezzo = prz;
            codice = cod;
            nome = nm;
        }

        // setters
        public void setDep(String rep) {
            this.department = department;
        }

        public void setPrz(double prz) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        public void setUdm(String udm) {
            this.unityOfMeasure = unityOfMeasure;
        }

        public void setQnt(int qnt) {
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }

        public void setCod(String cod) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public void setNm(String nm) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        // getters

        public String getDep() {
            return department;
        }

        public String getUom() {
            return unityOfMeasure;
        }

        public double getPrz() {
            return price;
        }

        public int getQnt() {
            return quantity;
        }

        public String getCod() {
            return code;
        }

        public String getNm() {
            return name;
        }

        public double getTotal() {
            return quantity * price;
        }

        public void remove() {

            this.quantity--;
        }



        public String toString() {

            // ----quantity not less than 0 ----

            if (quantity < 0) {

                System.out.println(quantity = 0);
            }

            return String.format(department + ";" + unityOfMeasure + ";" + quantity + ";" + "€" + formatter.format(price) + ";"
                    + code+ ";" + name + " \n");

        }

    }
```

Shop Class:

```
public class Shop implements Serializable {

    public List<Product> collection;

    public Shop() {
        collection = new ArrayList<Product>();

    }

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        collection.add(product);

    }

    public void sellProduct(String name) {
        for (Product product : collection) {
            if (name.equals(product.getNm())) {
                if (product.getQnt() >= 0) {
                    prodotto.remove();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void duplicatedProduct(String code) {
        for (Product product : collection) {
            if (code.equals(product.getCod())) {
                System.out.println("Error. Duplicated product");
            }
            return ;
        }
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String total = "\n";
        Iterator<Product> i = collection.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Product l = (Product) i.next();
            total = total + l.toString();

        }
        return total;
    }

}
```

Main Class:

```
public class Main {

    static String fileName = null;
    static Shop shp = new Shop();
    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    static boolean running = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        while (running) {
            System.out.println("\nPress 0 to load inventory. " + "\nPress 1 to save and quit"
                    + "\nPress 2 to add product to the inventory" + "\nPress 3 to find a product"
                    + "\nPress 4 for the total value of the inventory");
            int answer = in.nextInt();
            switch (answer) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println("Insert the name file to load.");
                Loading(in.next());
                break;
            case 1:
                saveAndQuit();
                break;
            case 2:
                addProduct();
                break;
            case 3:
                inputCode();
                break;
            case 4:
                inventoryValue();
                break;

            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static void inventoryValue() throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("SHOP.txt"));
        scanner.useDelimiter(";|\n");

        Product[] products = new Product[0];
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String department = scanner.next();
        String unityOfMeasure = scanner.next();
        int quantity = scanner.nextInt();
        double price = scanner.nextDouble();
        String code = scanner.next();
        String name = scanner.next();

        Product newProduct = new Product(department, unityOfMeasure, quantity, price, code, name);
        products = newProduct(products, newProduct);

        double totalValue = Arrays.stream(products).mapToDouble(p -> p.quantity * p.price).sum();
        System.out.println("Total Value: " + totalValue + "\n\n");

        for (Product product : products) {
            System.out.println(product);

            }

           }

        }

        private static Product[] newProduct(Product[] products, Product productToAdd) {
        Product[] newProducts = new Product[products.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(products, 0, newProducts, 0, products.length);
        newProducts[newProducts.length - 1] = productToAdd;
        return newProduct;
        }


    private static void inputCode() throws IOException {

        String code;
        String line = null;

        System.out.println("\nInsert code: ");
        code = in.next();
        try {

            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("SHOP.txt");

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] token = line.split(";");

                if ((";" + line + ";").contains((";" + code + ";"))) {

                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }

            bufferedReader.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Impossible to open the file ");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("error opening the file ");

        }

    }

    private static void addProduct() {

        String department;
        String unityOfMeasure;
        int quantity;
        double price;
        String code;
        String name;

        System.out.println("\ninsert department: ");
        department= in.next();
        System.out.println("\ninsert unity of measure: ");
        unityOfMeasure = in.next();
        System.out.println("\ninserit quantity: ");
        quantity = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\ninsert price: ");
        price = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("\ninsert code: ");
        code = in.next();
        System.out.println("\ninsert name: \n");
        name = in.next();

        Product p = new Product(department, unityOfMeasure, quantity, price, code, name);
        shp.addProduct(p);

    }



    private static void saveAndQuit() {

        running = false;

        PrintWriter printWriter = null;

        try {
            printWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("SHOP.txt", true)); 
            printWriter.println(shp);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (printWriter != null) {
                printWriter.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Loading(String name) throws IOException {
        FileReader fr;
        fr = new FileReader("SHOP.txt");

        BufferedReader br;
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String s;

        while (true) {
            s = br.readLine();
            if (s == null)
                break;
            System.out.println(s);

        }
        br.close();
        fr.close();
    }
}
```

This is the content of the txt File (SHOP.txt) where products are stored :

```
H;L;10;10,50;83259875;YellowPaint
E;U;20;1,50;87678350;Lamp
H;L;10;10,50;83259891;BluePaint
H;L;10;10,00;83259892;RedPAint
H;U;30;12,00;98123742;Hammer
G;U;80;15,00;87589302;Seeds
G;U;3;130,00;17483921;Lawnmower
```

this is the error that i expect to solve:

Total value: 105.0

H;L;10;€10,50;83259875;YellowPaint

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException 
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source) 
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source) 
at Main.inventoryValue(Main.java:68) 
at Main.main(Main.java:47)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you could debug your code and see what goes wrong

Comment: `double price = scanner.nextDouble();` The price field is not a double: "€10".

Comment: Also "10,50" works only with the proper `Locale`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp my professor requested to use that symbol in order to specify that is the price. That works and i dont think that is the problem. i have this in my Product class : 

public String toString() {
return String.format(department + ";" + unityOfMeasure + ";" + quantity + ";" + "€" + formatter.format(price) + ";"+ code + ";" + name + " \n"); }

Comment: "€10,50" is **not** a double! It is a string that can't be parsed to double by the scanner. You have to read it as a string and then implement some method for parsing the amount (double) out of it. Double can contain numbers and decimal separator, not currency symbols for sure.

Comment: I ran your code and it fails with the `€`. I removed the `€` and it worked. (I also replaced the "," with "." as that is locale specific.) https://ideone.com/5vfS9W

Comment: This is a bit strange. The output suggests that the first line can get read and the exception occurs on the seconds line in the text file, but as the others say, having a currency sign on the numbers should prevent a successful parsing in the way you do it currently in your code. Can you please provide a [mcve] as well as the text file?

Comment: Simple answer to your question `How can I solve this problem?` is `By the debugger` , I am sorry, but I am voting to close the question, due the fact the issue can be resolved by debugging of the code. And you have the answer anyway, in the post below (and comment above).

Comment: Why is there no `€` in the text file anymore? Have you removed them?

Comment: @Tom I noticed in this moment that the symbol were not showed. Anyway i can't run properly my program

Answer (score 1):

In your file where you say it is storing a double for the price, it should just be a decimal value. You have a '€' symbol in front of it and a ',' instead of a '.'. scanner.nextDouble() will not work if there is another symbol there. I'd recommend to store your prices without the currency symbol and a decimal rather than a comma and just append the '€' in front of wherever you plan on showing your total as so:

```
System.out.println("Total Value: €" + totalValue + "\n\n");
```